# How many cells needed to build the classifying space $BG$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group of cohomological dimension $n$.

Apart from the unresolved ambiguity pertaining to the Eilenberg--Ganea conjecture, it is known that we can find an $n$-dimensional model of the classifying space $BG = K(G,1)$.

It is also not hard to see that $BG$ needs to have cells in every dimension $j \leq n$: otherwise $EG^{(j-1)}$ would be a simply-connected acyclic space, hence already equal to $EG$, which is impossible by the assumption on $\text{cd}(G)$.

*My question now is: what is the smallest number of $j$-cells that $BG$ can have?*

For $G = \mathbf{Z}^n$ the count is $\binom{n}{j}$, and in general the number of $1$- and $2$-cells are the minimal number of generators and relations of a presentation of $G$, so can be $2$ (except for $G = \mathbf Z$ where $n = 1$) and $1$, respectively.

Comment: $G=\mathbb{Z}^n$ is exceptional in that the minimal $BG$ model is a compact 
orientable *manifold*, and therefore satisfies Poincare duality, Morse inequalities, etc., and in which Lusternick-Schnirelmann category is well studied. But in most cases, especially if $G$ is a Bieri-Eckmann duality group with dualizing $\mathbb{Z}G$-module $\mathbb{D}$ concentrated at a homological dimension $\nu>0$, then i don't think anybody knows how to count cells of *any* $BG$ model, nevermind the minimal $BG$ models which are no longer manifolds but necessarily *singular* topological objects.

Comment: Evenmore explicit geometric $BG$ models from geometric topology (arithmetic, knots, surface groups, etc) are typically neither minimal nor simplicial. An exception is the well-rounded retract model $W=W_n$ of $PGL(\mathbb{Z}^n)\backslash PGL(\mathbb{R}^n)/SO(n)$, consisting of all flat $n$-dimensional tori whose $1$-systoles generate $\mathbb{Q}^n$ in rational homology. Here the cells are naturally parameterized by certain collections of simple closed curves on the torus. But the $G$-orbits of these collections is equivalent to the explicit $\mathbb{Z}G$-module structure of $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: I not aware of a useful exact formula in the generality of the question, but for any skew field $K$ and homomorphism $\phi: G \to K^\times$ there is a lower bound of $\dim_K H_j(BG;K^\phi)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A group $G$ is of type $\mathcal{F}_n$ if it has a $K(G,1)$ with finite $n$-skeleton. Let $F_2$ be the free group on $2$ generators. Consider the kernel of the map $F_2\times F_2 \times \cdots \times F_2 \to \mathbb{Z}$, sending each generator to $1$. Then the kernel is of type $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ but not of type $\mathcal{F}_n$. This was proved by Stallings for $n=2$ and Bieri for $n>2$, see the discussion and links [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1465330). Taking $n\geq 3$, one gets finitely presented groups of finite cohomological dimension which do not have finite $n$-skeleton.

Nevertheless, one can ask your question for groups of cohomological dimension $n$ and type $\mathcal{F}_n$. For surface groups, and more generally 1-relator groups without torsion, this is known. A 1-relator group $G$ without torsion has presentation complex a $K(G,1)$, and cannot have a complex with fewer cells unless it is free.

For 3-manifold groups, this is a well-studied question when the $K(G,1)$ is a manifold and the cell structure is a handle structure. In this case, the number of cells is determined by the Heegaard genus of the manifold. There are [known algorithms](https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2018-0023) to compute this. However, the [rank and the Heegaard genus can differ](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-2013-00767-5). So there can be a $K(G,1)$ with fewer $1$-cells than the Heegaard genus. Most likely the rank of $3$-manifolds (so the minimal number of $1$-cells in a $K(G,1)$) is computable for $3$-manifolds, but it has only been [proved in special cases](https://doi.org/10.2140/gt.2005.9.375). I'm not sure though whether the minimality of the number of 2-cells has been addressed. The minimal number of 3-cells is $1$. An interesting possibility is that for a CW complex with a minimal number of $2$-cells, the number of $3$-cells or 1-cells might not be minimal.

In general, I'm not sure how much is known about this question, I'm just addressing the few special cases that I am familiar with to show how complex the answer can be.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer from which I learnt a lot! I am mostly interested in the case of bigger $n$, though. Another (related) more specialized question one could ask there is the following: if $M^n$ is a closed aspherical manifold, can it happen that the minimal number of $j$-cells in a CW-model of $M$ is smaller than $\binom{n}{j}$?

Comment: @JensReinhold The Heisenberg manifold (compact three dimensional nilmanifold) does not satisfy your binomial coefficient bound. Compare Pete L. Clark's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434384/the-heisenberg-manifold. More generally, you should compare your binomial coefficient bound with the Toral Rank Conjecture. Manifolds with $M^n$ with toral rank $<n$ are likely going to be counterexamples to your $nCj$ lower bound.

Comment: @JHM right, and cross with tori or with itself to get examples in all dimensions.